# SASS Built-in moules Error: Invalid CSS after

Tags: sass, module, gulp

I do not connect the built-in modules, or I do not use them correctly. Please help me. I use the gulp, and I can't understand why I have the error:

`Error: Invalid CSS after "...  $height: math": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".div($size, 2)"`

scss file

```
@use 'sass:math';

$height: math.div($size, 2);
```

gulp file

```
...
function styles() {
  return gulp
    .src("./src/scss/*.scss")
    .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        cascade: false,
      })
    )
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I used gulp-sass, instead of gulp-dart-sass.

because sass:math Compatibility: Dart Sass since 1.23.0

Comment: Where did you make this correction? What file? What is the corrected code to resolve the error? I am having the same error and don't understand how to correct it.

Comment: npm uninstall gulp-sass, and npm install gulp-dart-sass